# Is there an Angular way of doing: document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a div with the id of 1. I'm trying to set the display to none dynamically. Is there an Angular way of doing this. Currently, I'm using vanilla javascript. I was asking about doing this dynamically because there will be over 60 divs that will be created from an array.

In my html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; i = index;">
    <div id={{i}} (click)=hideDiv()></div> 
</div>
```

In my method

```
hideDiv() {
return document.getElementById('1').style.display = "none";
}
```

That works but I'm looking for the Angular way of doing the above.

It was suggested that I use @ViewChild. Here's what I've changed. I can't use a Template Reference Variable as the html divs are created dynamically. Unless someone can let me know how to create the template variables dynamically. Although I don't think it's possible to create template variables with a loop.

```
@ViewChild('imgId', { static: true }) elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
imgId: string;
```

Then in the method I have:

```
this.imgId = event.path[0].attributes[1].value;
 this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
```

The event.path[0].attributes[1].value gets me the id of the image. The imgId shows when I console log it. It's still not changing the display on the div to none. Also I'm getting the error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: How does your html look like?

Comment: I added the html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) query in Angular to do this. In your component, define a query like this:

```
@ViewChild('#1') elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
```

Implement the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) interface in your component, and inside it, use this:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Thank You, how do you use a variable in place of the '#1'

Comment: I've tried to use the @ViewChild but it's still not working. I can't use the AfterViewInit because that only fires once. I need this to work from a method.

Comment: You did not mention before that you needed this to be reusable for any selector or for a list of elements. ViewChild will not work in either case. Take a look at Mario Figueiredo's answer, which seems to be more appropriate for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `ngIf` for this

**Component**

```
  shouldDisplay: boolean = true;

  hide(): void {
    this.shouldDisplay = false;
  }
  show(): void {
    this.shouldDisplay = true;
  }
```

**Html**

```
<button (click)="hide()">Hide</button>
<button (click)="show()">Show</button>
<div *ngIf="shouldDisplay">this is the content</div>
```

Here is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5atqro?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Angular way:
template

```
<div *ngIf="showMe"></div>
```

or

```
<div [hidden]="!showMe"></div>
```

TypeScript:

```
showMe: boolean;

hideDiv() {
    this.showMe = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic items where your don't know how many you will get the best approach would be to add a directive that would store and adjust that for you:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[hide-me]' })
export class HideDirective {
  @Input() id!: string;
  @HostBinding('style.display')
  shouldShow: string = '';
}
```

then in your component just address them by ID:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
    <div hide-me id="{{index}}" (click)="hideDiv(index)">Some value</div> 
  </div>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(HideDirective) hideDirectives!: QueryList<HideDirective>;

  items = [null, null, null];

  hideDiv(id: number) {
    this.hideDirectives.find((p) => p.id === id.toString()).shouldShow = 'none';
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnrdhv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

An angular official example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnrdhv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, Renderer2 would've been my first choice. I would've liked to be able to use it with the dynamic divs. Thanks for the solutions. It works.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the div reference to the hideDiv method directly in the Dom using a template variable like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; i = index;">
<div #divElement (click)=hideDiv(divElement)></div>
```

And in your hide div method you will have access to the element directly

```
hideDiv(div) { div.style.display = "none";}
```

Here is a Stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w1s3jl

There are many ways to do this, but in my opinion this is a simple solution the achieves your goal with less code.

**PS**:
It is always recommended to use the angular [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to manipulate Dom elements. This service has the method [setStyle](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setStyle) which you can use for your code.

Comment: Have you checked my stackblitz example? In your example the divs are rendered with an ngFof which works with template variables as in my Stackblitz example.

Comment: I did and thank you. I got it to work by looking at your example.